# Set variable values of usercontrol from MainWindow.xaml.vb

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, background

Ok so I have a MainWindow and a user control that gets contained in the MainWindow at runtime when the MainWindow is loaded.
Now I want to change the Usercontrol's grid background from the MainWindow.

I've tried:

```
Sub button_click(...) Handles button.click
UserControl1.grid1.Background = CType(FindResource(AdonisUI.Brushes.Layout4BackgroundBrush), Brush)
End Sub
```

But this gives me a error in the code suggestion box as follows:

```
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

I've also tried:

```
Sub button_click(...) Handles button.click
Dim u = Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of BuildUIContainer).FirstOrDefault
u.grid1.Background = CType(FindResource(AdonisUI.Brushes.Layout4BackgroundBrush), Brush)
End Sub
```

The code compiles but the background color of the grid does not change when button is clicked.

Comment: where is the `AdonisUI.Brushes.Layout4BackgroundBrush` resource defined?

Comment: @mdziadowiec It comes with the Import of the AdonisUI namespace. I mean by adding the line 'Imports AdonisUI' at the top.

Comment: @mm8 during the MainWindow.Loaded event.

Comment: @mm8 problem solved with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the `UserControl` during the `Loaded` event, you could just store a reference to it in a variable and access it directly using this one at a later stage, e.g.:

```
Private theUserControl As UserControl1

Sub OnLoaded(...) Handles Loaded
    theUserControl = New UserControl1()
    ...
End Sub

Sub button_click(...) Handles button.click
    theUserControl.Background = ...
End Sub
```